# Slow query with sub SELECTs

Tags: mysql, performance, subquery

Unsure how to optimize this query but it and about 15 variations of it need to run for a dashboard page. Any and all suggestions are welcomed! Thanks.

Time: 0.466s

Time without sub-selects: 0.058s

```
SELECT  
    gallery.go_id AS id,
    (SELECT meta.value FROM meta WHERE meta.model = "Gallery_other" and meta.model_id = gallery.go_id and meta.key = "cache_sort_title_text" LIMIT 1) AS `sort_cache_sort_title_text`, 
    (SELECT CAST(meta.value AS SIGNED) FROM meta WHERE meta.model = "Gallery_other" and meta.model_id = gallery.go_id and meta.key = "cache_sort_title_int" LIMIT 1) AS `sort_cache_sort_title_int` 
FROM  
    arGalleryOther gallery  
WHERE  
    gallery.go_visible = 1  
    AND  
    gallery.go_added <= "2017-11-09 17:55:46" 
    AND ( 
        gallery.go_maingal = 9  
        OR  
        FIND_IN_SET(9, gallery.go_othergal) 
    ) 
ORDER BY 
    gallery.go_added DESC, 
    sort_cache_sort_title_text ASC, 
    sort_cache_sort_title_int ASC 
LIMIT 
    4
```

[image: MySQL Explain]

```
CREATE TABLE `arGalleryOther` (
  `go_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `go_code` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `pr_id` varchar(150) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `go_name` varchar(75) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `go_name_noint` varchar(75) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `go_name_int` int(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `go_maingal` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `go_othergal` text CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `go_added` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `go_visible` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `go_horiz` varchar(15) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'h',
  `go_vert` varchar(15) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL DEFAULT '*',
  `go_override` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `go_thumb` varchar(25) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `go_keywords` text CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `go_html_page` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `go_phototype` enum('H','V') CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'H',
  `go_notes` text CHARACTER SET latin1,
  `go_nudity` enum('YES','NO') CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'NO',
  PRIMARY KEY (`go_id`),
  KEY `idx_visible` (`go_visible`),
  KEY `idx_added` (`go_added`),
  KEY `idx_maingal` (`go_maingal`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `idx_othergal` (`go_othergal`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=4527 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE `meta` (
  `meta_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `model` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `model_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `key` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `value` text,
  `serialized` enum('false','true') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'false',
  `type` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`meta_id`),
  KEY `idx_model` (`model_id`,`model`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `idx_key` (`key`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `idx_model_id` (`model_id`),
  KEY `idx_model_key` (`model`,`key`,`value`(255)) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=368839 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT
```

Answer (score 2):

Critique of indexes:

`go`:

```
  KEY `idx_visible` (`go_visible`),  -- DROP; indexing flags is rarely useful
  KEY `idx_maingal` (`go_visible`, go_added),   -- for WHERE
```

`gl`:

```
INDEX(visible, added)  -- in this order
```

`meta`:

```
  PRIMARY KEY (`meta_id`),  -- see below
  KEY `idx_model` (`model_id`,`model`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `idx_model_id` (`model_id`), -- DROP since the above handles it
  KEY `idx_model_key` (`model`,`key`) USING BTREE  -- Prefix indexing useless here
```

For key-value, it is rarely necessary to have an `AUTO_INCREMENT` id (`meta_id`) since there is probably a combo of other columns that is unique.  See my tips [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#speeding_up_wp_postmeta).

Answer (score 0):

You can move the subqueries to a single join.  That ought to help.

```
SELECT  
    gallery.go_id AS id,
    sort_cache.value_text AS `sort_cache_sort_title_text`, 
    sort_cache.value AS `sort_cache_sort_title_int` 
FROM arGalleryOther gallery  
        LEFT JOIN 
            (
                SELECT MAX(value) value_text, 
                     MAX(CAST(value AS SIGNED)) value, 
                     model_id 
                FROM meta 
                WHERE meta.model = "Gallery_other" 
                        and meta.key = "cache_sort_title_text"
                GROUP BY model_id
            ) AS sort_cache ON sort_cache.model_id = gallery.go_id 
WHERE  
    gallery.go_visible = 1  
    AND gallery.go_added <= "2017-11-09 17:55:46" 
    AND ( 
        gallery.go_maingal = 9  
        OR  
        FIND_IN_SET(9, gallery.go_othergal) 
    ) 
ORDER BY 
    gallery.go_added DESC, 
    sort_cache_sort_title_text ASC, 
    sort_cache_sort_title_int ASC 
LIMIT 4
```

Answer (score 0):

I 100% appreciate you taking the time to rewrite the query for me. Yours managed to get it down to .2s. Wrapping a select * () around it and sorting by the sub-select columns outside of the primary query dropped it to .014s.

```
SELECT * FROM ( 
    SELECT  
        gallery.gl_id AS id,  
        (    SELECT  meta.value
            FROM  meta
            WHERE  meta.model = "Gallery"
              and  meta.model_id = gallery.gl_id
              and  meta.key = "cache_sort_title_text"
            LIMIT  1
        ) AS `sort_cache_sort_title_text` , 
        (    SELECT  CAST(meta.value AS SIGNED)
            FROM  meta
            WHERE  meta.model = "Gallery"
              and  meta.model_id = gallery.gl_id
              and  meta.key = "cache_sort_title_int"
            LIMIT  1
        ) AS `sort_cache_sort_title_int` 
    FROM  
        arGalleries gallery  
    INNER JOIN   
        arGalleryPages gallery_page  
        ON  
            gallery_page.gp_id = gallery.gp_id  
    INNER JOIN  
        bgProducts product  
        ON  
            product.pr_id = gallery.pr_id  
    WHERE  
        gallery.gl_visible = 1  
        AND  
        gallery.gl_added <= "2017-11-10 00:05:35"  
        AND ( 
            gallery_page.gp_main = 7  
            OR  
            FIND_IN_SET(7, gallery_page.gp_other) 
        )        
ORDER BY 
    gallery.gl_added DESC, 
    gallery.mt_id ASC 
LIMIT 
    6) AS temp 
ORDER BY 
    sort_cache_sort_title_text ASC, 
    sort_cache_sort_title_int ASC
```